# C - How to use a string with scanf multiple times

Tags: c

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
     char terminal[100];

     printf("Enter cmds: ");
     scanf(" %s", terminal);

     if(strcmp(terminal, "help") == 0){
           printf("test");
           scanf(" %s", terminal); // trying to detect if a user types
                                   // "help" the menu will pop up again
     }

     return 0;
     }
```

When a user types "help", the menu pops up, (good so far). But when they type "help" again, the menu does not pop up. Does anybody know what is going on?

Comment: where did you code for the _again_ part?

Comment: Perhaps a `do...while` loop is what you want?

Comment: How is VB.NET related to this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial comments hit the nail on the head here. You need to *loop* over new input multiple times. This can be done fairly easily.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char terminal[100];

    printf("Enter cmds: ");

    // this expression will return zero on invalid input, exiting the loop
    while (scanf("%99s", terminal) == 1) {  
        // your if statement and other code you want to repeat go here.
    }
}
```

To better encapsulate this kind of behaviour, defining some sort of function that compares strings and returns an element of an enum is a very common practice, but not required in this question.